# Matplotlib image put in PYQT widget

Tags: python, qt, matplotlib

iv got a problem.
I have to create widget in my GUI which has embedded my image (256x256 matrix). The image which I created is done with a help of matplotlib. 
Heres the code

```
import scipy
import scipy.io
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy

def openFile(name):``
    return scipy.io.loadmat(name)

def showPlot(mat, key):
    plt.imshow(mat[key],cmap='gray', interpolation='nearest', vmin=None, vmax=255)
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.show()


name = 'skull_stripped.mat'
key = 'skull_stripped'
mat = openFile(name)
showPlot(mat,key)
```

How can I embed the "mat" variable in QTpython GUI widget?

Comment: Where is your GUI?

Comment: The problem is indeed unclear. The code you show does produce a plot of the matrix. It would also produce this plot if the whole thing was embedded into PyQt. If that fails for you you need to show the code that you have the problem with.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and i solved implementing this function connected to one button i created in my GUI. You can use QFileDialog() function to browse in the folder where your mat file is placed. Than you use the function getOpenFileName(). This function return a tuple where the first element is the url of the file. Using scipy.io.loadmat you can import the file and manage it for your aim.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog, QDialog 
import sys
import scipy.io.spio
import numpy as np

class Window(QMainWindow):
   def __init__(self):
      super(Window, self).__init__()
      self.title =("My_Gui")
      self.top = 100
      self.left = 100
      self.width = 1680
      self. height = 880

      self.InitWindow()

  # Definition of buttons
   def InitWindow(self):

     self.Import = QPushButton("Import Data", self)
     self.Import.setGeometry(20, 50, 150, 50)
     self.Import.clicked.connect(self.importdata)

# Display interface
     self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
     self.setGeometry(self.top, self.left, self.width, self.height)
     self.show()

   def importdata(self):
     global img, img1, img2
     fd = QFileDialog()
     filenameraw = fd.getOpenFileName(self, caption="", directory="")
     filenameraw = filenameraw[0]
     raw = spio.loadmat(filenameraw)


App = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Window()
sys.exit(App.exec())
```

the variable raw will contains your mat file and you can use it as you need.